# Why is my card deck adding more cards in a sequence the more you draw in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a deck of cards, and it's' gone very good for the most part. I'm stuck right now because when I try to draw a card, it adds a card every time. For example, during the third loop of drawing cards, I ask to draw three. It actually gives me information for five cards. Please help if you can.

Here's my code:

````
class Card:
    def __init__(self, direction, arrows):
        self.direction = direction
        self.arrows = arrows
    def show(self):
        print("This card has", self.arrows, self.direction, "facing arrows.")
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()
    def build(self):
        for d in ["north", "east", "south", "west"]:
            for a in range(1, 4):
                self.cards.append(Card(d, a))
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r], = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]
    def drawCard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []
    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
        return self
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
cardamount = 24
while cardamount > 1:
    choice = input("What do you want to do?\n")
    deck = Deck()
    joe = Player
    if choice == "draw":
        numberchoice = (int(input("How many?\n")))
        if numberchoice <= cardamount:
            for count in range(numberchoice):
                deck.shuffle()
                joe.draw(deck)
                joe.showHand()
                deck.shuffle()
                cardamount = cardamount - 1
    else:
        print("NOT AN OPTION")
print("You ran out of cards.")```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
for count in range(numberchoice):
    deck.shuffle()
    joe.draw(deck)
    joe.showHand()
    deck.shuffle()
    cardamount = cardamount - 1
```

Each time through the loop, you draw one card and then show the whole hand.

So if you draw three cards, you would draw the first card and show it, then draw the second card and show both of them, then draw the third card and show all three, for a total of six cards shown.

To fix this, move `showHand()` outside of the draw loop.